# Is this a bug in Scala 2.10 String Interpolation inside a multiline String with backslash?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, string-interpolation

Using Scala 2.10.0-RC1, I tried to use String Interpolation inside a Windows file path, e.g. like this:

```
val path = s"""c:\foo\bar\$fileName.csv"""
```

And got an Exception

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
```

Without the multiline string literal (`"""`) it works just fine 
val path = s"""c:\foo\bar\$fileName.csv""" 
    val path = s"c:\foo\bar\${fileName}.csv" //> path  : String = c:\foo\bar\myFile.csv

Further testing to reproduce the issue:

```
object wcScala10 {

  util.Properties.versionString   //> res0: String = version 2.10.0-RC1
  val name = "James"              //> name  : String = James
  val test1 = s"Hello $name"      //> test1  : String = Hello James
  val test2 = s"""Hello $name"""  //> test2  : String = Hello James
  val test3 = """Hello \$name"""  //> test3  : String = Hello \$name
  val test4 = s"""Hello \$name""" //> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
                                  //>   String index out of range: 7
}
```

**Is this exception due to a bug? or am I simply not allowed to use backslash before the $ sign when doing String interpolation?**

Here is more of the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps$.apply$extension(StringOps.scala :39)
    at scala.StringContext$.treatEscapes(StringContext.scala:202)
    at scala.StringContext$$anonfun$s$1.apply(StringContext.scala:90)
    at scala.StringContext$$anonfun$s$1.apply(StringContext.scala:90)
    at scala.StringContext.standardInterpolator(StringContext.scala:120)
    at scala.StringContext.s(StringContext.scala:90)
    at wcScala10$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(wcScala10.scala:9)
    at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$$anonfun$$exe
 cute$1.apply$mcV$sp(WorksheetSupport.scala:76)
    at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$.redirected(W
 orksheetSupport.scala:65)
    at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$.$execute(Wor
 ksheetSupport.scala:75)
    at wcScala10$.main(wcScal
 Output exceeds cutoff limit.
```

**Update:**

Now marked as fixed for Scala 2.10.1-RC1

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6631

By the way, even after the fix, the right way to do interpolation and avoid escaping is using `raw`:

```
val path = raw"c:\foo\bar\$fileName.csv"
```

e.g.

```
val fileName = "myFileName"               //> fileName  : String = myFileName
val path = raw"c:\foo\bar\$fileName.csv"  //> path  : String = c:\foo\bar\myFileName.csv
```

Comment: p.s. I am aware it's an RC, and bugs are likely, just not sure if it is

Comment: You report put this on https://issues.scala-lang.org. Look what i get when i remove a "\" 
`scala> s"""c:\foo\bar$fileName.csv"""
res9: String = c:♀oo?arX.csv`

Comment: Wow. nice one :) I tried to register there, it got a message stating I have no permissions, do you know what I'm missing?

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6631 created

Comment: @SantoshGokak thanks! How does one gets access there by the way?

Comment: Signup @ https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Signup!default.jspa

Comment: @SantoshGokak yes, I forgot to mention that I tried that. I get this message: "You do not have a permission to log in. If you think this is incorrect, please contact your JIRA administrators."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String interpolation notation takes over control of whether a string is a raw string or not.  All that triple-quoting gets you is the ability to quote single quotes.  If you want no interpolation, use `raw"Hi $name"` instead.  (Except `raw` is also buggy in 2.10.0; a fix is in for 2.10.1 AFAIK.)

That said, this is not a very friendly way to deal with the situation of having a malformatted string.  I'd classify it as a bug, only because it's returning an out-of-bounds exception not something that says an escape code can't be completed.

Note: these break also:

```
s"Hi \$name"
s"""Hi \"""
```